# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning When Using loc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Have a general question on assignments with indexing/slicing using .loc.

Assume the below DataFrame, df:

```
df:    
    A   B   C
0   a   b   
1   a   b   
2   b   a   
3   c   c   
4   c   a
```

code to reproduce:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aabcc'), 'B':list('bbaca'), 'C':5*[None]})
```

I create df1 using:

```
df1=df.loc[df.A=='c']

df1:
    A   B   C
3   c   c   
4   c   a
```

I then assign a value to C based upon a value in B using:

```
df1.loc[df1.B=='a','C']='d'
```

The assignment works, but I receive a SettingWithCopy warning.  Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected functionality?  I thought that using .loc would avoid chained assignment.  Is there something that I am missing?  I am using Pandas 14.1

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is a bug but running your code I see that `df1` is modified but `df` is not which is not what you are intending. You've assigned `df1` to be a reference to a slice of your `df` but now performing the `loc` assignment has only modified `df1`, it smells like a bug to me but I am not 100% sure if this is intended or not

Comment: In this case it was my intention to only modify df1, was just curious as to why I was receiving the SettingWithCopy warning when doing so, but I think you actually answered it.  In the above, df1 is a reference to a slice of df.  If I create df1 using df1=pandas.DataFrame(df.loc[df.A=='c']) then the warning goes away.

Comment: the point here is that you are modifying a frame that is in effect a slice of another. you normally need to copy to avoid this warning as you can sometimes operate on a copy.

Comment: Rather than just taking a reference, you could be more explicit in your code and do `df1=df.loc[df.A=='c'].copy()` this will make it clear your intentions and not raise a warning.

Answer (score 11):

@EdChum answer in comments to OP has solved the issue.
i.e. replace

```
df1=df.loc[df.A=='c']
```

with

```
df1=df.loc[df.A=='c'].copy()
```

> this will make it clear your intentions and not raise a warning