# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning when using iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to change values in my DataFrame after merging it with another DataFrame and coming across some issues (doesn't appear to be an issue prior to merging).

I am indexing and changing values in my DataFrame with:

```
df.iloc[0]['column'] = 1
```

Subsequently I've joined (left outer join) along both indexes using merge (I realize left.join(right) would work too). After this when I perform the same value assignment using iloc, I receive the following warning:

```
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

A review of the linked document doesn't clarify the understanding hence, am I using an incorrect method of slicing with iloc? (keeping in mind I require positional based slicing for the purpose of my code)

I notice that df.ix[0,'column'] = 1 works, and similarly based on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569384/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-with-iloc?noredirect=1&lq=1) I can reference the column location with df.columns.get_loc('column') but on the surface this seems unnecessarily convoluted.

What's the difference between these methods under the hood, and what about merging causes the previous method (df.iloc[0]['column']) to break?

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489875/pandas-settingwithcopywarning-when-using-loc

Comment: Have similar problem. Did see, No joy, my intention is to update the values, not create a copy of the dataframe and leave the original as is. Also: my .iloc comes from grp_kfold.split, so I just have the numbers, cannot do df.A=x

Answer (score 1):

You are using chained indexing above, this is to be avoided "`df.iloc[0]['column'] = 1`" and generates the SettingWithCopy Warning you are getting. The Pandas docs are a bit complicated but see [SettingWithCopy Warning with chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for the under the hood explanation on why this does not work.

Instead you should use `df.loc[0, 'column'] = 1`

[`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is for "Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array."

[`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is for "Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position."

Answer (score 0):

It sucks, but the best solution I've come so far about **updating** a dataframe's column based on the .ilocs is find the iloc of a column, then use .iloc for everything:

column_i_loc = np.where(df.columns == 'column')[0][0]
df.iloc[0, column_i_loc] = 1

Note you could also disable the warning, but really do not!...

Also, if you face this warning and were not trying to **update** some original  DataFrame, then you forgot to make a copy and end up with a nasty bug...